# How to rearrange JavaScript array using match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Let say that we have the JavaScript array `arr`, where each `arr[i]` contains a sentence. Now If we want to search for the sentences that contain a particular string `str`, we can use `match` to find these sentence using

```
var newarr = [];                
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(arr[i].toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase()){       
newarr[newarr.length] = arr[i];             
}
}
```

The new array `newarr` will contain only the sentence that contain the string `str`. Now, is there a way to rearrange `newarr` so that the sentences containing `str` in beginning be first, then the ones that containing `str` in the middle then the ones containing `str`in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method available on Arrays can take a custom function that compares elements and sorts according to that. Your custom sort function needs to take two arguments, `a` and `b`, and return a number; `a` and `b` are elements of your array which are being compared. The number that your function returns tells the `sort` function whether `a` or `b` should come first, according to the following rules:

- if the returned number is `<0`, then `a` comes before `b`
- if the returned number is `>0`, then `b` comes before `a`
- if the returned number is `0`, then `a` and `b` are "the same" order-wise

So to order an array of strings according to where a substring `str` appears, then you can do something like this:

```
var arr = ['bbbab', 'bbabbb', 'abbb', 'bbbba'];

// Our substring.
var str = 'a';
// Make copy of array.
var newarr = arr.slice()
// Sort.
newarr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.indexOf(str) - b.indexOf(str);
});
console.log(newarr); // => ["abbb", "bbabbb", "bbbab", "bbbba"]
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are elements of your array that are being compared.

Comment: Is there a way to trim each array element using `trim()` while sorting?

Comment: What about `abbb`, `abbbb`, `abbbbb`, etc. How these should be arranged

Comment: @user3741635, what do you mean by "trim"? If you want you can just do something `newarr = arr.map(function(elt) { return elt.trim(); });`.

Comment: I mean use `trim()` to remove any space from left and right.

Comment: @Tushar can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @user3741635, see my previous comment, I have edited it to include a way to trim each of the elements.

Comment: They all starts with `a`, but their length is different. `indexOf` will return 0 for all. According to me, length should also be considered while sorting elements

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you're saying. It's a good question, but I don't think it's necessary to worry about in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You have forgotten one parenthesis in your if condition.

http://jsfiddle.net/pandeyaditya/LbwgfLvt/

Check below code :

```
var arr = ["JS is fun", "JS Rocks", "JS is for techies"];
var newarr = [];
var str = "fun";
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(arr[i].toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase())){       
newarr[newarr.length] = arr[i];             
}
}
   alert(newarr);
```

Comment: In the future, you can just edit the question to fix small issues like this.